# growth function with higher tail growth

Tags: r, curve-fitting, growth-model

I am trying to fit a model to performance data by age. However the model I am getting predicts a much slower growth rate at high ages than the data would suggest (by looking at it).
Is there a better way to create this model?

```
df<-tribble(
  ~age, ~performance,
  11.0,  1.26,
  16.0,  2.475,
  23.5,  2.754,
  34.5,  3.127,
  44.5,  3.263,
  54.5,  3.323,
  64.5,  3.378
)    
f <- nls(performance ~ SSgompertz(age, Asym, b2, b3), data=df)
    plot(performance ~ age, data = df)
    curve(predict(f, newdata = data.frame(age = x)), add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without more specification many kind of functions may be appropriate. For example this one :

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Do you have an example how to fit this in R?